# python cgi script receiving form data

Tags: python, html, forms, cgi

I am trying to create a python program that will receive information from a form that is using html. 
This is what i have for my html code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> NBA Survey! </title></head>
<form method = "POST" action = "result.py">
<hr>
Who do you think is the best Small Forward in the NBA right now? <br>
          <input type="radio" name="9" value="Chris Paul"> Chris Paul  <br>
            <input type="radio" name="9" value="Tony Parker"> Tony Parker <br>
            <input type="radio" name="9" value="Stephen Curry"> Stephen Curry <br>
            <input type="radio" name="9" value="Rajon Rondo"> Rajon Rondo <br>
            <input type="radio" name="9" value="Derrick Rose"> Derrick Rose <br>
            <input type="radio" name="9" value="Kyrie Irving"> Kyrie Irving <br>
            <input type="radio" name="9" value="Russell Westbrook"> Russell Westbrook <br>
            <input type="radio" name="9" value="Other"> Other <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

for the code in python, this is what i have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi
import sys
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if form.getvalue('9') = 'Chris Paul':
    f1.write('Chris Paul')
f2 = open('results.txt','a')
g2 = f2.read().split(',')
page += 'Chris Paul: ' + g2.count('Chris Paul')
```

I am trying to create a python page where after i hit submit on the html page, it will redirect the user to a new page where the results of the survey will be shown. The survey will be on a server where other people are able to vote.

The page would look like:

Chris Paul: (Number of Votes)
Tony Parker: (Number of Votes)
etc...

All help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to narrow your question and do some more personal researches before obtaining any *concrete* help here. But...

...at first sight, your question*s* raise some more question*s*:

- How will persist the data between the "vote" form and the "result" page? I'm not familiar with low level usage of the Python CGI module, but as far as I can see, you just store your data in plain Python variables that will be gone once the script has finished. Or, if I am not wrong, CGI scripts run just for *one* request.
- Are you sure you want to do a *redirect*? If so, your "form" processing CGI script just have to respond with the corresponding [301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) or [302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) http status code. On the other hand, you might wish to display the poll results as the "normal" response of the form? In that case, just produce here a valid HTML document and returns it with a [200](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_200#2xx_Success) status code.
- How will you deal with "unexpected" form data? You cannot trust incoming requests. And maybe a request has been forged, transmitting say, a vote for "Donald Duck". You have to be prepared for that (BTW, "9" is a very bad non descriptive name for your form field...)
- That could be seen as a *minor* problem (or even *no* problem), but ... hey ... we are professional here! So, your HTML lack of "body" tag and is not properly intended.

Still some work to do! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is my first time doing something like this.

Comment: The result page is a simple blank page that will show the # of votes that each radio option has gotten in numeric value.

Comment: The page that i intended to create is a html survey page with a result page that uses python as an engine. With this, i believe that the data will be stored in python.
"redirect" may have been a bad word choice here. In the html page, the submit button already brings the user to the result page already, so i guess i am fine in that category.
Well this will be a simple survey using Radio options so unexpected data will not appear. The other choice will be a radio as well.

Comment: @user2480957 The one _main_ thing that I don't understand is how will the data _persist_ from one request to the next. Say I vote for "Tony Parker" (Yeah! France!). I am the first voter. So the counter for Tony change from 0 to 1. Great. And the script produce a nice output showing 100% vote for Tony. And the script ends. All Python "ordinary" variable are lost...

Comment: ... few seconds after that, someone else post a vote. Say for Derrick Rose (Go Chicago Bulls!). But, this is a brand new run of your script. With brand new variables. Derrick Rose vote count change from 0 to 1. And so get 100% of the votes. Etc. You have to find a way for your script to _remember_ things from one run to an other. Moreover, that "memory" should be smart enough to deal properly with two concurrent ("simultaneous") access -- like if two users vote at the same time.

Comment: wait so wouldn't the information be appended into the result.txt so that it would change the value of each set of data while saving the information.

Comment: That "result.txt" part is quite confusing. In your code snippet, you "write" to "f1" which is not open, nor closed. Then you "read" from "f2" which is opened on "append" mode. I could _imagine_ you are using that file to store the votes ... but using a text-file with **exclusive write** access will _not_ address my concern about concurrent votes. In that case, one of the voter will open (and _lock_) the file and the second will not be able to open the file (since it _is locked_ by the first one).

Comment: This is a kind of "vicious" bug, since this will work properly while your are alone testing ... but will fail mysteriously sometimes on production.

Answer (score 0):

Read Sylvain Leroux's answer first.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi
import sys
from collections import Counter

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

name = form.getvalue('9')
if name:
    with open('results.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(name + '\n')

print('Content-Type: text/plain\n')

with open('results.txt') as f:
    counts = Counter(line.strip() for line in f)

for name, count in counts.most_common():
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, count))
```